# React project runs locally but build does not

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have a pretty simple project that looks up some info from a mongo table and lists it on the screen. There is a loading state to show a spinner and message, and when i run 'yarn build' and host the output files, it just gets stuck on the loading screen, and i only see some randomy console.log outputs, not all my code.

What is going wrong with the build process that works fine when running locally with 'yarn start' ?

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { ZOHO } from "./vendor/ZSDK";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link,
  NavLink,
  Redirect,
  withRouter,
} from "react-router-dom";
import JiraTable from "./components/JiraTable";
import CircularProgress from "@mui/material/CircularProgress";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";

function App() {
  console.log("INITIALIZING");

  const [zohoContactId, setContactId] = React.useState("");
  const [usrEmail, setUsrEmail] = React.useState("");

  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = React.useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function init() {
      console.log("BEFORE PAGELOAD");
      try {
        await ZOHO.embeddedApp.on("PageLoad", function (data) {
          console.log("PageLoad", data);
          console.log(data);

          //Custom Business logic goes here
          let entity = data.Entity;
          let recordID = data.EntityId;

          // Set data we want from CRM into props
          ZOHO.CRM.API.getRecord({ Entity: entity, RecordID: recordID })
            .then((data) => {
              console.log(data);

              setContactId(data.data[0].id);
              setUsrEmail(data.data[0].Owner.email);

              console.log(usrEmail);
              setIsLoaded(true);
            })
            .catch((e) => console.log(e));
        });

        console.log("AFTER PAGELOAD");
        return await ZOHO.embeddedApp.init();
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
    init();
  }, []);

  const ContentLoader = () => {
    // handle rendering conditionally based on AJAX response
    if (error) {
      // API Data Error State: render the error state
      return <div>Error</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      // API Data Not Loaded: render the loading progress spinner
      return (
        <div align="center">
          <CircularProgress />
          <Typography variant="h2"> Loading data....</Typography>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      // API Data Loaded Succesfully:
      // render the completed interface with data loaded, triggered by the state update of isLoaded and !error (no error)
      return <JiraTable custId={zohoContactId} usrEmail={usrEmail} />;
    }
  };

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Paper>{ContentLoader()}</Paper>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Yarn Build Output
[image: yarn build output]

Local build using yarn start which works fine
[image]

Comment: Did you check the network requests panel?

Comment: Your logs are configured to only show "Info", you may have deselected Error from the dropdown at some point. Above it is showing there is an error and warnings. Maybe those are of use.

Comment: @marc_s Let's see your package.json file

Comment: Try runni g yarn build on local

Comment: Probably your ZOHO file has not been transfered to your build directory, how are you handling you build process, is it `webpack` or `CRA`?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have a secret/password for the ZOHO environment set up as an environment variable (as you should!)

In that case it would run locally, but you'd have to set it up as well at the distribution env...